# Displaying metadata for multiple authors in Elementor's "widget posts"

Tags: multi-author

I'm facing a little issue with WordPress, and I could really use your help. You see, I'm not very experienced with coding, so I'm hoping you can lend me a hand in the right direction.

I'm using the PublishPress Authors plugin to have multiple authors on my website, and Elementor as my page builder. But here's the catch: when I create a page with the latest posts using Elementor's "widget posts" feature, it only displays metadata for one author. However, I want to show metadata for all the authors associated with the posts.

Now, here's where I'm struggling. I think the problem lies in the code, but I'm not sure which file to look at or where exactly to make the changes. It would be fantastic if you could guide me on this!

I've heard that the PublishPress Authors plugin has this cool "get_coauthors" function that can fetch an array of co-authors for a post. That sounds like the key to the solution! But I could use some assistance in locating the code that needs modification and making the necessary changes.

Thank you so much for your kind assistance and support. I truly appreciate your patience with a beginner like me!